# Why $ \ \lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor= j(2j+1)$

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

Can someone please explain to me why is this happening?

In general $\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor$ is $j$ when $j^2\le n<(j+1)^2=j^2+2j+1$, which is $2j+1$ times, so if we group like terms together we find
$$ S_k = \sum_{n=1}^{k^2-1} \lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor = \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} j(2j+1)$$

The only thing I don't understand is why $$  \ \lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor=  j(2j+1)$$

Comment: It isn't.  Note that your two sums have different indices

Comment: Denote by $j$ the floor of $\sqrt n$ for some fixed $n$. Then if $n$ runs from $1$ to $k^2-1$ the corresponding $j$ values run from $1$ to $(k-1)$. This explains the limits in the $j$-sum. Now for a fixed $j$ how many times it is taken? It is taken for $n$ between $j^2$ and $(j+1)^2-1$. Yes, $2j+1$ times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be clearer: $$\sum_{n=1}^{k^2-1} \lfloor \sqrt n\rfloor = \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} \sum_{n=j^2}^{(j+1)^2-1} \lfloor \sqrt n\rfloor = \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} \sum_{n=j^2}^{(j+1)^2-1} j = \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} ((j+1)^2-j^2) j = \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} j (2j+1) $$

Comment: It seems correct but I don’t understand why there are two sums